# How to prove the extension of a positive continuous linear operator is still positive?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $E$ be a real ordered Banach space with the positive cone $P$ of $E$.
It is easy to see that the positive cone $P$ is the closed convex cone of $E$.

We assume that $E_0 := P - P $  is a dense linear subspace of $E$. This means that $P$ is a total cone of $E$ (i.e., $\overline{P-P} = E$).

We know that if there is a **bounded linear operator** $A \colon E_0 \to E_0$, by Continuous Linear extension theorem, then the operator $A$ has a unique extension
$\bar{A} \colon E \to E$ such that $\bar{A}$ is also a bounded linear operator with $\bar{A} v = Av$ for each $v \in E_0$ and $\| \bar{A} \| = \| A \|$.

*My question is that* if we suppose further that the operator $A$ is **positive** (i.e., $A(P) \subset P$), then is its extension $\bar{A}$ still positive (i.e., $\bar{A}(P) \subset P$)? If so, how to prove it?

Any ideas or suggestions are most welcome! Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Its not necessarily true unless you have some further restrictions. For example let $E$ be $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ and $P$ be the cone of such sequences with only entries $≥0$ and infinitely many non-zero entries. Take $E_0$ to be the dense subspace of such sequences with only finitely many non-zero elements, then $E_0\cap P= 0$ and any linear map sends $E_0\cap P$ into $P$. It does _not_ follow that the extension sends $P$ to $P$.

Comment: You should want at least $E_0\cap P$ to be dense in $P$ and possibly for $P$ to be closed, in that case the result is easy.

Comment: Thank you so much @s.harp. You are right, I have edited my question again. In that case, it is clear that $E_0 \cap P = P$ with $P$ being closed. Thus, for any fixed $v \in P$, by positive property of $A$, $Av \in P$, which in turn yields that $\bar{A} v = Av \in P$, by the construction of the unique extension $\bar{A}$. This means that $\bar{A}$ is indeed positive as desired. To show this result, I haven't used the closeness of the cone $P$. So, I'm wondering that is the closeness of $P$ necessary here?

Comment: Since $P \subset E_0$ we have $A|_{P} = \bar A|_{P}$. Thus, $A(P) = \bar A(P)$.

Comment: Thanks @gerw. I agree with you. May I ask you one more question please? As $E_0$ is a dense subspace of $E$, we know that the well-known BLT (bounded linear transformation) extension theorem is talking about the existence of a unique extension of a bounded linear operator $A \colon E_0 \to E$ rather than $A \colon E_0 \to E_0$ I wrote above, I'm not 100% sure that does BLT extension theorem apply to $A \colon E_0 \to E_0$? Is it correct? Many thanks again:)

Comment: @Paradiesvogel re closedness: you have misunderstood my conditions, I want $E_0\cap P\subset P$ to be dense and I want $A(E_0\cap P) \subset P$ in addition to closedness of $P$. I don't demand $E_0\cap P = P$ nor do I demand $A(E_0\cap P)=P$, which are things you seem to have assumed.

Comment: About your second question, there is a general statement that a Lipschitz continuous map $D\to Y$ where $Y$ is a complete metric and $D$ is dense in some complete space $X$ can be uniquely extended to a map $X\to Y$. The completeness of $Y$ is absolutely necessary. Taking here for example $A=\mathrm{id}:E_0\to E_0$ (where $E_0$ is dense in $E$) then $A$ admits _no_ extension continuous $E\to E_0$ unless $E_0=E$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply @s.harp. That's a huge help:) I really appreciate it!

Comment: @s.harp sorry for bothering you again, may I ask that given a bounded linear operator $A \colon E_0 \to E_0$ where $E_0$ is a dense subspace of a real Banach space $E$, does there exist a unique extension $\bar{A} \colon E \to E$ such that $\bar{A} |_{E_0} = A$ and $\|\bar{A}\| = \|A\|$? Many thanks again:)

Comment: @Paradiesvogel yes, because $A:E_0\to E_0$ can also be seen as a map $E_0\to E$ since $E_0\subset E$. Now the codomain is a Banach space and you can apply the principle.

Comment: @s.harp your kind help is much appreciated! Would you mind me asking you another question please? What if given a bounded linear operator $A \colon P \to P$ (as $P$ is positive cone of $E$, this operator is linear in the sense that $A(av+b u)= aAv+bAu \in P$ for any $u,v \in P$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$.), now could this operator $A$ be extended uniquely to a bounded linear operator $\hat{A} \colon E \to E$? Thanks so much again:)

Comment: This depends on what you mean with positive cone. For example, some definitions allow $\{0\}$ to be a positive cone, here it is clear that extensions will not be unique. Things are also a bit different depending on whether or not we are in a complex or in a real vectorspace. If you look at $E=\Bbb C$ and $P= \{\alpha + i\beta\mid \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R_+\}$ then the map $A:P\to P, \alpha+i\beta\mapsto \alpha+\beta$ admits _no_ extensions, since $\Bbb C$ linearity fails already on $P$ itself.

Comment: If you have the following conditions on $P$ and $A$ then (i) uniqueness and (ii) existence of extensions are given: (i) $\mathrm{span}_{\Bbb K}P$ is dense in $E$, (ii) For any $x,y\in P$, $a,b\in\Bbb K$ so that $ax+by\in P$ you have $A(ax+by)=aA(x)+bA(y)$. If any of these conditions do not hold then the consequences fail.

Comment: Thanks @s.harp. I only want to restrict $E$ to be a real Banach space, so that we only need to focus on $\mathbb{K}= \mathbb{R}$. Regarding condition (ii), did u mean that "for any $x,y \in P$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ so that $ax+by \in P$ and we have $A(ax +by) = a A(x) + b A(y)$."?

Comment: @s.harp regarding this question, would you mind to take a look at my previous question posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502144/a-consequence-of-a-linear-transformations-mathcall-x-y-between-two-real please? In that case, your condition (i) is satisfied naturally and condition(ii) is also satisfied for $A$ with any nonnegative real number $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Thanks a million:)

Comment: It took a while, but I realised my statement was false. I had assumed continuity of a linear map on a positive cone was the same as Lipschitz continuity, just like in normed vector spaces. But this is not true, however if you have Lipschitz-continuity then it works. I wrote up a counter-example in your other question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question asked in the OP:

> Let $P$ be a cone in a Banach space $E$ so that $E_0=\mathrm{span}(P)$ is dense in $E$, if a continuous linear operator $A:E_0\to E$ is positive, does it follow that its closure $\overline{A}: E\to E$ is positive?

This is true for these special conditions, namely since $P\subset E_0$ we have $\overline A(P) = \overline A\lvert_{E_0}(P) = A(P)\subset P$ by the positivity of $A$.

Perhaps more natural is the question what happens when $P\not\subset E_0$. But we cannot be too general, for example if $E_0$ and $P$ have intersection $\{0\}$ then any map $E_0\to E$ is positive, even the restriction of non-positive maps will be so.

I think the clearest demands to make are that $E_0\cap P$ is dense in $P$ and that $P$ is a *closed* cone. Then for any $p\in P$ we have a sequence $p_n\in E_0\cap P$ with $p_n\to p$. So
$$\overline A(p) =\lim_n \overline A(p_n) =\lim_n\, A(p_n).$$
Now by positivity of $A$ we have that $A(p_n)$ is in $P$ and by closedness of $P$ the limit of this must lie in $P$. Thus $\overline A(p)\in P$. So $\overline A$ is a positive linear map.